# Tkinter Custom widget: Is there any way to change the style of a ttk.Entry when inserting a textvariable via .configure?

Tags: class, tkinter, widget

I have a custom ttk.Entry widget. I need to do an action when modifying the 'textvariable' via the .configure method, but I'm not getting it.

An example:

```
self.user = StringVar()
self.user.set('test')
self.my_ent = custom_Entry(self.frame)
self.my_ent.configure(textvariable=self.user)
```

When there is 'textvariable' in .configure, I would like to change the widget style

I tried to recreate the .configure method inside my custom widget, but I can't call .configure inside the .configure

```
def configure(self, cnf=None, **kw):
    for k, v in kw.items():
        if k == 'textvariable':
            self.delete('0', END)
            self.configure(style='custom.TEntry')
            self['show'] = ''
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
```

I can't do this inside .configure:

```
self.configure(style='custom.TEntry')
self['show'] = ''
```

---

complement

[image]

sample code
https://www.mediafire.com/file/ehopuk4ljyj1mpi/frm_main.py.zip/file
note: I updated the file

Comment: Why don't you write your own function called `configure_entry` or something, and have it get a textvariable as an argument, and then just run as many `self.my_ent.configure()`s as you need inside it?

Comment: That's what I tried to do but couldn't. I can't do this "self.configure(style='custom.TEntry')" inside my custom function inside my widget. And I have no idea how to get around this

Comment: I don't think you understand what I was trying to say. You wrote a function that overshadowed the original `configure()` function. I meant that you should write your own function that doesn't overshadow another function. Also, why can't you call `configure()` in a custom function? Do you get error messages? Please [edit] your question to provide them.

Comment: Can you explain what you are actually trying to do? Sounds like a xy problem. Also I believe you can call `super().configure()` inside your `configure()` method

Comment: Here is a complete example file.
When inserting a '.configure(textvariable=' I need to change the style of the entry https://www.mediafire.com/file/ehopuk4ljyj1mpi/frm_main.py.zip/file

Comment: Please don't link to code on another site. Take the time to create a functioning [mcve] in your question.

Comment: Sorry, I did the minimal example, I can't answer my own question, the moderators have deleted the answer. so I left the code on that link.

Comment: You  can [edit] your question to add more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the base `configure` method via [super()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super)

This is the first paragraph in the documentation for `super()`:

> Return a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent or sibling class of type. This is useful for accessing inherited methods that have been overridden in a class.

For example:

```
def configure(self, **kwargs):
    super().configure(**kwargs)
    if "textvariable" in kwargs:
        self.delete(0, "end")
        super().configure(style='custom.TEntry', show='')
```

Comment: @MrkalvinBs Maybe check [this](https://github.com/nihaalnz/mtk/blob/main/placeholders.py) out

Comment: Thanks for the help, as suggested by @Bryan Oakley it worked as expected, I just needed to remove this line, which was wrong
'self.delete(0, "end")'

Comment: @MrkalvinBs: I added the `delete` command because you had it in the code in your question.